# finding a subset of an array centred on a given item

Tags: javascript, algorithm, pseudocode

Am trying to find a better way to return a range of array values from an existing array.

For an list/array of numbers, say:

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

I want to select a range of 5 numbers centred around the a given number x.

(Psuedocode since I guess i'm really referring to array indexes here.. values don't matter just the position)

So if x is 4, we can return a range centred on that:

[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

But if x is 2, we cannot centre the range, so we'd have to do our best and return:

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

... Not centered, but atleast we have returned 5 numbers.

Similarly if x is 10:

[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

... 10 is the limit, so cannot centre, so the 5 numbers are pushed backwards.

I've got this working in some JS code, but it feels like too much code with too many conditionals.

Wondering if there is any known method or algorithm that can help?

Comment: As I understand, you always choose the centre index, then you could easily break the problem into choosing a subset from the left of the centre and another subset from the right of the centre, assuming that there is always a solution, you could easily compute when you need to carry more elements from a side. Choosing a subset should be simple enough.

Comment: I think this would be best posed to [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). It's not a good fit here...

Comment: @Sebivor, i see no code here, so no codereview.

Comment: @NinaScholz OP mentions that he/she has working code, and this question is *too broad* for StackOverflow, as it currently stands. Sit on whatever side of the fence you like. I'm voting to close.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];


function findSubset(arr, item) {
  // check index
  var index = arr.indexOf(item);
  // if element not found then return
  if (index == -1) return;

  // if element is at starting position 
  // then return first 5 element
  if (index < 3)
    return arr.slice(0, 5);

  // if elements at ending position
  // then return last 5 elements
  if (index > arr.length - 4)
    return arr.slice(-5);

  // otherwisse return elements based on the index
  // within the required range
  return arr.slice(index - 2, index + 3);
}

console.log(
  findSubset(arr, 1),
  findSubset(arr, 10),
  findSubset(arr, 5),
  findSubset(arr, 9),
  findSubset(arr, 3)
)
```

A generic solution with a varying count.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];


function findSubset(arr, item, count = 5) {
  var index = arr.indexOf(item),
    // calculate floor and ceil value for comparison 
    // and getting subset array
    f = Math.floor(count / 2),
    c = Math.ceil(count / 2);
  
  if (index == -1) return;
  
  if (index < c)
    return arr.slice(0, count);

  if (index > arr.length - c - 1)
    return arr.slice(-count);

  return arr.slice(index - 2, index + c);
}

console.log(
  findSubset(arr, 1, 3),
  findSubset(arr, 10, 7),
  findSubset(arr, 5, 1),
  findSubset(arr, 9, 4),
  findSubset(arr, 8, 1),
  findSubset(arr, 7, 3),
  findSubset(arr, 3, 9)
)
```

Comment: The generic approach does not work for 2,2 or 2,1 -> Empty array. Also does not work for 5,3 -> returns 4 items or 5,2 -> return 3 items

Answer (score 3):

You could move the found index by subtracting the half size and take a max value for negative indices and a min value for indices which are greater than the array length minus the size of the wanted sub array.

> ```
>  value  array                           index  adj  max  min
>  -----  ------------------------------  -----  ---  ---  ---
>             v                              
>     2    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10     1    -1    0    0
>         [             ]
>
>                      v        
>     5    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10     4     2    2    2
>               [             ]
>
>                                     vv        
>    10    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10     9     7    7    5
>                        [              ]
> ```

```js
function getSub(array, value, size) {
    var index = array.indexOf(value) - (size - 1) / 2,
        max = Math.max(index, 0),
        min = Math.min(max, array.length - size);
    return array.slice(min, min + size);
}

console.log(getSub([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 2, 5));
console.log(getSub([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 5, 5));
console.log(getSub([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 10, 5));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: `size - 1` seems a bit off for even sizes as `.slice` truncates it, but `size >> 1` or `size / 2` should be fine

Comment: @Slai, i thought, the value of size is always odd, because of the structure with a middle index.

Comment: sorry, never mind .. - 1 seems a bit more appropriate if even sizes are allowed

Comment: Did you notice that when `size` = 2n, `min` can be a floating point number ? This means that it is implicitely converted to an integer somewhere in the process. Harnessing the tiniest details of the language to produce super short source code is quite smart, clap' clap' +1

Comment: @leaf, instead of a size, it could be a padding for each side. then the result is more flexible thean the wanted fixed result array length of 5.

Answer (score 0):

Recipe of the below algorithm :

1. Create subset `s` of max length `a.length`.
2. Calculate starting index that is index of `x` minus half the length of `s`.
3. Adjust starting index to prevent index overflow.
4. Copy `s.length` items from `a` to `s`.
5. Return `s`.

Array `s` is guaranteed to be contained in array `a` since `s` is never bigger than `a`.

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

function subset (a, x, n) {
  var s = new Array(Math.min(a.length, n));
  var j = a.indexOf(x) - Math.floor(s.length / 2);
  // overlap to the left : [.[1]2 3 4]
  if (j < 0) {
    j = 0;
  } 
  // overlap to the right : [1 2 3[4].]
  else if (j > a.length - s.length) {
    j = a.length - s.length;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    s[i] = a[j + i]
  }
  return s;
}

console.log("x = 2, n = 4, s =", subset(a, 2, 4).join(","));
console.log("x = 9, n = 4, s =", subset(a, 9, 4).join(","));
console.log("x = 5, n = 4, s =", subset(a, 5, 4).join(","));
console.log("x = 2, n = 5, s =", subset(a, 2, 5).join(","));
console.log("x = 9, n = 5, s =", subset(a, 9, 5).join(","));
console.log("x = 5, n = 5, s =", subset(a, 5, 5).join(","));
console.log("x = 5, n = 20, s =", subset(a, 5, 20).join(","));
```

However, hard to know if it's shorter than your own code since you didn't provide it :-|